# Сумма квадратов в linq

Tags: c#, linq

Задание: Завершите функцию квадратной суммы, чтобы она возводила в квадрат каждое переданное в нее число, а затем суммировала результаты.

Вот код, не могу сделать что бы суммировал результат.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2 };

    Action<int> action = new Action<int>(Result);
    Array.ForEach(a, action);
    
    static void Result(int b)
    {
        int c = b * b;

        Console.Write($"{c} ");

    }
```

Comment: так у вас тут нет результата. У вас функция `Result` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: `var result = a.Select(x=>x*x).Sum();` ?

Comment: И поменять void на int. И на вход подавать не одно число, а массив. И... мммм, а вы точно уверены, что вам нужны делегаты?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, вы помогли разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Непонятно зачем здесь делегаты, по классике жанра можно вообще без Linq. Вот первый вариант:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2 };
    var sum = GetResult(a);
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}

int GetResult(int[] nums)
{
    var result = 0;
    
    foreach (var num in nums)
        result += num * num;
    
    return result;
}
```

Вот второй вариант:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2 };
    foreach (var num in a)
    {
        GetResult(num);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Sum);
}

private static int Sum = 0;

void GetResult(int num)
{
    Sum += num * num;
}
```

И если уж нужен Linq - то можно и так:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2 };
    
    var sum = a.Select(x=>x*x).Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Или объединить Select и Sum:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2 };
    
    var sum = a.Sum(x => x * x);
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Выбирайте любой из них.

Comment: На правах изврата `var sum = Array.ConvertAll(a, x => x * x).Sum()`

Comment: И еще `a.Aggregate((sum, x) => sum + x * x)`

Comment: @A K, большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! И за правки которые вы сделали!

Comment: @aepot, не совсем понял, что означает "На правах изврата", объясните пожалуйста. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @aepot мсье знает толк в аггрегации :)

Comment: @MarvinDigital `Array.ConvertAll` возвращает новый массив, под который выделяется память, с значениями, возведенными в квадрат. А тот же `Sum(x => x * x)` просто проведет вычисления без создания нового массива, а следовательно сэкономит память, и возможно отработает быстрее. Поэтому решение с `Array.ConvertAll` в данном конкретном контексте не считается эффективным.